# How do I make smooth curves for a CNC?

Tags: svg, arduino, cnc

I making an Arduino-based X-Y laser cutter. I've built the mechanics for it and accomplished basic motion, but I am having trouble getting it to plot lines and curves. I eventually want to be able to convert SVG or Illustrator files to Gcode or have the Arduino interpret and plot them directly

[A picture of my setup.](http://instagram.com/p/qyQ4SbLlqW/)

There are libraries like GRBL and Rstepper that provide 2-wire (step and direction) instructions based on Gcode. The problems is that I'm driving two stepper motors using ULN2003 chips, which use 4 wires to step through the phases of the motor.

**Could I make either of these libraries work for 4-wire control?**

---

If not, I will need to find another way to plot my designs.

How I'm currently thinking of making functions for SVG or G-code style instructions.

```
//given a new position to go to and how we want to get there (i.e. curves)
for (i=0;xposition!==newx;i++) //run until x gets to the right spot
{
//get the values for X, Y, NewX, NewY, and any other parameters (e.g. for curves)
//figure out how many steps (say, +1 or -1) x should take for cycle number i
//figure out how many steps y should move given new x
//make the x stepper step the right number of steps
//make the y stepper step the right number of steps
//delay (control speed for adequate laser burning & don't make the steppers angry)
}
```

Will that be too slow?

Answer (score 1):

Having been down this road and wasted much time, I would **strongly** suggest that you just get a couple of [Easy Drivers](http://www.schmalzhaus.com/EasyDriver/) for $15-$20 ea. and move on with your project using GRBL. It is a great library and there is a nice Java-based open source laser cutter front end project called [Visicut](http://hci.rwth-aachen.de/visicut). Visicut can handle either SVG files or gcode.

If you *must* use the chips you have, the [Connecting Grbl](https://github.com/grbl/grbl/wiki/Connecting-Grbl) pages lists this site [Driving stepper motor using ULN2003](http://ssecganesh.blogspot.de/2008/05/driving-stepper-motor-using-uln2003.html) but cautions: *"It is out-dated and uses Grbl v0.7."*

*(But seriously, hardware choices because "that is what one has" rather than what might be easier to implement can really suck the joy out of a fun hacker project like you have going)*

Comment: I would upvote if I had enough reputation. Thanks for the comment. As for the Easy Drivers, I had feared as much. Visicut is a great lead.

I might still try to solve the X-Y plotting for ULN2003 problem to avoid putting my sub-$100 project over. It might still be a fun way to learn more about engineering using geometry.

Unfortunately, the links provided (which I've seen a couple other places) don't seem to contain the actual info. The content must have been gutted or moved. Thanks again!

Comment: @Corey - heh...ok, so you are going down the rabbit hole. take notes! (seriously). You will want to check out Bresenham + DDA line algorithms (breaking curves into straight lines - that is how it is done). The GRBL source code also has good comments in it @ motion profiles (acceleration control). The RepRap project has various open source branches which do motion control and which might be easier to understand/hack (because they are more verbose/less efficient than GRBL) Have fun! :-)

Comment: You replied forever ago. Your answer was great. For anyone else looking, I've stuck with GRBL for both this laser cutter and a 3D printing project. GRBL executes GCode and a variety of things can interface with it. I use Illustrator to make an SVG then convert it using either Inkscape with a GCode plugin called Unicorn. To send this GCode to the microcontroller running GRBL, I use UGS (Universal GCode Sender) when I have a file or gctrl for Processing for custom programs (like auto-generating zen garden patterns on a sand drawing bot).

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but there are a few modified versions of GRBL that support unipolars now. Here are the links:

- https://github.com/TGit-Tech/GRBL-28byj-48
- https://github.com/ruizivo/GRBL-28byj-48-Servo (this one didn't work when I tried it but it might work on your setup)

Note that in my testing the x/y axis invert messed everything up. It might be because I'm using a coreXY setup though.